# Struggling to figure out how to set these constraints

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently setting up a few different tables for which I have to use  certain constraints.  I have been getting on okay but I am stuck with the following:

- Limiting the 'Country' column to a choice between UK, USA and Australia
- Creating the 'ImageFilename' column so that each record must have an extension of .JPG

Is there a specific constraint for these examples or is it a case of thinking outside the box here? I've tried to think of ways to use the current constraints I know but I'm stumped.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

edit: would it perhaps be a CHECK constraint?

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 8.0, [MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraints.](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464)

Even if MySQL were to add support for CHECK constraints, I wouldn't use that as a solution, because when you eventually add New Zealand and Canada, or if you support .PNG in addition to .JPG, you'd have to redefine the constraints.

For the countries I would create a lookup table, and a foreign key constraint to restrict your country column.

```
CREATE TABLE Countries ( Country VARCHAR(75) PRIMARY KEY );

ALTER TABLE DifferentTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (Country) REFERENCES Countries(Country);
```

This allows you to support new countries simply by INSERTing a new country name into the Countries table.

For the image extension, I can think of two alternatives:

1. Define a trigger that throws a [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) if the filename doesn't match the right extension.

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER ImageFilenameIns BEFORE INSERT ON DifferentTable
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     IF (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.ImageFilename, -1) <> '.JPG') THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You must use a .JPG filename';
     END IF;
   END

   CREATE TRIGGER ImageFilenameUpd BEFORE UPDATE ON DifferentTable
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     IF (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.ImageFilename, -1) <> '.JPG') THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You must use a .JPG filename';
     END IF;
   END
   ```

   Remember to set [DELIMITER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) if you create this trigger using the `mysql` client or SQL script.

   Using the trigger solution requires redefining the trigger if you someday want to support .PNG or other extensions.
2. Define a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to represent the file extension, and make sure that references a lookup table of allowed file extensions.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ImageFileExtensions ( Extension VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY );
   INSERT INTO ImageFileExtensions (Extension) VALUES ('JPG');

   ALTER TABLE DifferentTable
     ADD COLUMN ImageFilenameExtension VARCHAR(3) AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(ImageFilename, -1)) STORED,
     ADD FOREIGN KEY(ImageFilenameExtension) REFERENCES ImageFileExtensions(Extension);
   ```

   With the latter solution, you can add support for a new file extension simply by INSERTing a new extension into the ImageFileExtensions table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is that you try to pull off but you can use IF in mysql:
* (for Creating):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
:row(row_id varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
:country varchar(25) NOT NULL CHECK (country IN ('USA','UK','Australia')),
PRIMARY KEY (row_id));
```

*Test whether two strings are the same and return "YES" if they are, or "NO" if not (for Selecting):*

```
SELECT IF(STRCMP(":country","UK") = 0, "YES", "NO");
```

or:

```
SELECT :row, CASE :Country
WHEN 'USA' THEN 1
WHEN 'UK' THEN 2
WHEN 'Australia' THEN 3
ELSE 'NO'
      END AS :row1, :row2, :row3
FROM :Table
```

but still you can do the same thing with PHP:

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
switch($country){
case "UK":
case "USA":
case "Australia":
   Model::DB->Post($country, "Country");
   break;
default:
   App::Error->Err("Invalid input - " . $country);
}
```